# JOrtho (Java Orthography Checker)

Tags: java, spell-checking

I'm new to JOrtho (Java Orthography Checker) project, wanna ask u how to use SpellChecker in the right way ? :

1. for example, how to add User dictionary ?
2. how to set new dictionaries ?
3. if i use Tokenizer, what to sent to itws constructor ?

I used this code: (is it ok ) ? :

```
SpellChecker.setUserDictionaryProvider( new FileUserDictionary());
SpellChecker.registerDictionaries( null, null); 
Tokenizer tok = new Tokenizer(SpellChecker.getCurrentDictionary(), SpellChecker.getCurrentLocale(),
SpellChecker.getOptions());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me;

```
FileUserDictionary f = new FileUserDictionary("path to dictionary folder");
SpellChecker.setUserDictionaryProvider(f);
SpellChecker.registerDictionaries(getCodeBase(),"en");
```

Answer (score 1):

Truth be told, the documentation for this project is rather scarce. Have you tried the [javadocs](http://www.inetsoftware.de/documentation/other-products/jortho/apispec/index.html) or the [sample code](http://www.inetsoftware.de/other-products/jortho/samplecode)?

Comment: yes, I did, I don't understand what new FileUserDictionary() exactly does? and how to use it? ..... all the docs says that u need to use FileUserDictionary if u wanna add new words to dictionary, and at the end register dictionaries (like dictionary_en.ortho) ..... ok i've done it but nothing happens..... and if i'll check words like --> AAA!!!, A&R ... they r left as valid words in English why ?